# Adding text to target node in gephi graph

Tags: python, r, gephi, social-media, network-analysis

I am trying to create a network of given data, in which source node(tweetid) target node(tweet has a link to another platform like news, youtube) edge type(a type of link like morality & ethics). I have created a network, and different indicates the different edge types morality & ethics and clustered point show twitter, news, youtube, others.

```
target node
id
facebook     
news
twitter
news
news
news

 source node
 1194697388650370000    
 1195602298237540000
 1195667383182130000
 1195673938459790000
 1195689221970910000

 Edge file
 source target               edgeType 
 1194697388650370000    facebook None 
 1195602298237540000    news     None 
 1195667383182130000    Instagram Morality & Ethics 
 1195673938459790000    news     None 
 1195689221970910000    news     None
```

[image]

Now, I want the highlight the target node (converging point) with a name like news, Instagram.
How can I do it in Gephi?

Comment: Have you tried adding values to the ‘Label” column in Data Laboratory? Just add labels to the converging points and eg refresh your Preview.

Comment: so, the label means like a retweet, likes to source_node

Comment: I guess by RT you mean an edge, no? Edges can also be labeled if I am not wrong.